# conceptual explanation of the red5 java class structure

Tags: java, server-side, red5, class-structure

I'm building a flash based videochat site on which users will create accounts and connect to other users in (for now) 1 on 1 chat rooms (not a porn site--I know you thought it).

I've installed red5 and built a few hello worlds, and now I find myself at a point where it would be REALLY helpful to have a good rundown of the concepts of the red5 api.

I've been digging through the fancycode api:

http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/

and the source:

http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/

and though I understand the individual classes I mull over, the big picture escapes me. I have a very solid understanding of flash/as3, so the client side work is a walk in the park, but since java is by no means my specialty and since there seems to be an overwhelming ratio of fluff&complaining:usefulInfo about red5 online I would really appreciate it if someone could either point me to a place where I could get an explanation of the red5 class structure and how one would go about building an application with it -- OR -- if someone with red5 server side experience could elaborate on the concepts of server side red5 application programming.

classes I'm especially interested in knowing more about (particularly how they fit together) are:

(MultiThreaded)ApplicationAdapter, IClient, IScope, Rooms.

also general approaches to how one might handle many users connecting to a server, and, from there, how you would go about connecting them to the correct (other) user.

In a nutshell I'm hoping that someone can show me the "big picture" of the red5 api structure so that I can bend it to my will!!! >:)

Thanks in advance!
-s33hunt

Answer (score 0):

This may get you started: http://www.red5tutorials.net/index.php/Tutorials

Alternatively, if you don't want to develop your own, and want to use a hosted API, check out OpenTok http://opentok.com

Comment: Thanks! tokbox is pretty cool, I've been checking it out all afternoon. I may use it for a quick proof of concept. I'd still love to understand the red5 library though -- anyone else able to explain the ideas behind the class structure so I might better understand how to build an application?

Comment: Hey, also, just spent some time at red5tutorials.net and got a better picture of some of the basic structure. Thanks!